# DB2 SQL Getting distinct value when grouping rows

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, case, distinct

BUSINESSTABLE looks like this:

```
HOTEL_CHAIN    HOTEL_LOCATION   HOTEL_OWNER
_____________________________________________________
Marriott       Las Vegas        Nelson
Best Western   New York         Richards
Best Western   San Francisco    Smith
Marriott       New York         Nelson
Hilton         Boston           James
```

I'm trying to execute an SQL statement in a DB2 database that groups these entries by HOTEL_CHAIN.  If the rows that are grouped together contain the same HOTEL_LOCATION or HOTEL_OWNER, that info should be preserved.  Otherwise, a value of 'NULL' should be displayed.  For example, both Marriott hotels have the same owner, Nelson, so I want to display that information in the new table.  However, each Marriott hotel is in a different location, so I'd like to display 'NULL' in that column.

The resulting table (HOTELTABLE) should look like this:

```
HOTEL_CHAIN    HOTEL_LOCATION   HOTEL_OWNER
_____________________________________________________
Marriott       NULL             Nelson
Best Western   NULL             NULL
Hilton         Boston           James
```

I'm trying to use the following SQL statement to accomplish this:

```
INSERT INTO HOTELTABLE(HOTEL_CHAIN,HOTEL_LOCATION,HOTEL_OWNER) 
SELECT
HOTEL_CHAIN,
CASE COUNT(DISTINCT(HOTEL_LOCATION)) WHEN 1 THEN HOTEL_LOCATION ELSE 'NULL' END,
CASE COUNT(DISTINCT(HOTEL_OWNER)) WHEN 1 THEN HOTEL_OWNER ELSE 'NULL' END,
FROM BUSINESSTABLE GROUP BY HOTEL_CHAIN
```

I get an SQL error SQLCODE-119 A COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN A HAVING CLAUSE IS NOT VALID.  It seems to be complaining about the 2nd HOTEL_LOCATION and the 2nd HOTEL_OWNER within my case statements.  I also tried using DISTINCT(HOTEL_LOCATION) and that threw another error.  Can someone please explain the correct way to code this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  Use `MIN()` and `MAX()`:

```
INSERT INTO HOTELTABLE(HOTEL_CHAIN,HOTEL_LOCATION,HOTEL_OWNER) 
    SELECT HOTEL_CHAIN,
           (CASE WHEN MIN(HOTEL_LOCATION) = MAX(HOTEL_LOCATION)
                 THEN MIN(HOTEL_LOCATION) ELSE 'NULL'
            END),
           (CASE WHEN MIN(HOTEL_OWNER) = MAX(HOTEL_OWNER)
                 THEN MIN(HOTEL_OWNER) ELSE 'NULL'
            END)
    FROM BUSINESSTABLE
    GROUP BY HOTEL_CHAIN;
```

Notes:

- Why not `COUNT(DISTINCT)`?  It is generally much more expensive than `MIN()` and `MAX()` because it needs to maintain internal lists of all values.
- I don't approve of a string value called `'NULL'`.  Seems like it is designed to foster confusion.  Perhaps just `NULL` the value itself?

Answer (score 0):

I agree Gordon for the null (gj Gordon).

other method

```
INSERT INTO HOTELTABLE(HOTEL_CHAIN,HOTEL_LOCATION,HOTEL_OWNER)

select distinct f1.HOTEL_CHAIN, 
       case when f2.HasDiffLocation is not null then 'NULL' else f1.HOTEL_LOCATION end as HOTEL_LOCATION,
       case when f3.HasDiffOwner is not null then 'NULL' else f1.HOTEL_OWNER end as HOTEL_OWNER
from BUSINESSTABLE f1
left outer join lateral 
(
    select 1 HasDiffLocation from BUSINESSTABLE f2b
    where f1.HOTEL_CHAIN=f2b.HOTEL_CHAIN and f1.HOTEL_LOCATION<>f2b.HOTEL_LOCATION
    fetch first rows only
) f2 on 1=1

left outer join lateral 
(
    select 1 HasDiffOwner from BUSINESSTABLE f3b
    where f1.HOTEL_CHAIN=f3b.HOTEL_CHAIN and f1.HOTEL_OWNER<>f3b.HOTEL_OWNER
    fetch first rows only
) f3 on 1=1
```

or like this :

```
INSERT INTO HOTELTABLE(HOTEL_CHAIN,HOTEL_LOCATION,HOTEL_OWNER)
select distinct f1.HOTEL_CHAIN, 
ifnull(f2.result, f1.HOTEL_LOCATION) as HOTEL_LOCATION,
ifnull(f3.result, f1.HOTEL_OWNER) as HOTEL_LOCATION,
from BUSINESSTABLE f1
left outer join lateral 
(
    select 'NULL' result from BUSINESSTABLE f2b
    where f1.HOTEL_CHAIN=f2b.HOTEL_CHAIN and f1.HOTEL_LOCATION<>f2b.HOTEL_LOCATION
    fetch first rows only
) f2 on 1=1

left outer join lateral 
(
    select 'NULL' result from BUSINESSTABLE f3b
    where f1.HOTEL_CHAIN=f3b.HOTEL_CHAIN and f1.HOTEL_OWNER<>f3b.HOTEL_OWNER
    fetch first rows only
) f3 on 1=1
```